# Relationship involving number of inversions of permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

Let

- $i,j\in \{1,\dots,n\}$
- $G_{n-1}$ be the set of all $(n-1)-$permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{j\}$.
- $C_n=\{\sigma\in S_n:\sigma(i)=j\} $ where $S_n$ is the set of all $n-$permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, $\sigma(i)$ returns the $i$th element of $\sigma$.

For any pair $\gamma\in G_{n-1} , \sigma\in C_n$ such that $\gamma(h)=\sigma(h) , h=1,\dots,i-1 $ and when $i<n$ we have  $\gamma(k-1)=\sigma(k) , k=i+1,\dots,n$ , or more visually appealing $\gamma = (\sigma(1) , \dots , \sigma(i-1) , \sigma(i+1) , \dots , \sigma(n) )$.

**Is there a nice relationship between number of inversions of $\gamma$, $N(\gamma)$ and that of $\sigma$ , $N(\sigma)$?** e.g. $N(\sigma) - N(\gamma) = i+j$.

I'm a total beginner in this area, so I prefer to define $N(\sigma)$ as the minimum number of swaps of consecutive integers $i\leftrightarrow i+1$ to reach $\sigma$ from the natural order $(1,\dots,n)$. I only notice that

- $|G_{n-1}|=|C_n| = (n-1)!$
- There is a bijection between $G_{n-1}$ and $C_n$ , e.g. $\gamma , \sigma$
- $N(\gamma),N(\sigma)$ are defined w.r.t. "natural orders" $(1,\dots,j-1,j+1,\dots,n)$ and $(1,\dots,n)$ resp.

Comment: A good place to start thinking would be to notice that $G_{n-1}$ is the _stabiliser_ of $j$ in the action of $S_n$ on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ - in particular is a subgroup of $S_n$, not just a subset. Notice also that $C_n$ is a _right coset_ of $G_{n-1}$, in particular it is $G_{n-1}(i\,j)$ where $(i\,j)$ is the transposition swapping $i$ and $j$. This explains why the two sets have the same size, and once you fix a coset representative $\rho$ (say $\rho=(i\,j)$), it gives you a bijection $G_{n-1}\to C_n\colon\gamma\mapsto \gamma\rho$.

Comment: As a separate remark, your definition of an inversion of a permutation differs from (ind is not equivalent to) the standard one, ie $N(\sigma)=|\{(i,j)\mid i<j\;\textrm{and}\;\sigma(i)>\sigma(j)\}|$. Do you mean to use a different definition of inversion? If so, is there a reason for calling your definition an inversion?

Comment: @DavidSheard Thanks for the info , however as I've almost no knowledge in this area , I'll need to do more research to understand your comment  . Also , I'm ok with the standard definition of inversion .

Comment: Do you mean that you meant to use the standard definition of inversion, and you would like your question answered using this definition? If so, can you edit your question to reflect this? One way to rephrase your definition to match the standard definition would be as follows: "$N(\sigma)$ as the minimum number of swaps of consecutive integers $i\leftrightarrow i+1$ to reach $\sigma$ from the natural order $(1,\dots,n)$".

Comment: @DavidSheard yes , I edited .

Comment: @DavidSheard  $\gamma \in G_{n-1}$ so its length is $n-1$ . Please definitely distinguish $G_{n-1} , C_n , S_n$ , otherwise it may be confusing . If my post is unclear/not easy to understand you may suggest me to edit  .

Comment: Ah I see, your notation is non-standard (at least to me) which is what tripped me up, but I think this now makes sense, thanks

Comment: There are $j - 1$ values smaller than $j$ and $n - j$ values larger than $j$.  There are $i - 1$ values before the ("missing") $i$th position and $n - i$ values afterwards.  Let $a$ be the number of values that are both before $i$th position and larger than $j$.  Then ....